# Sampling rate conversion and polyphase decomposition

Tags: multirate, polyphase

Can someone please explain the answer to this problem:

The sampling rate of a baseband signal shall be converted from 5 kHz to 7.5 kHz using the efficient polyphase implementation with a 'rotating' switch. How many polyphase components are required and how many steps must the switch be rotated?

Comment: lessee, for every 5000 input samples, you need to turn it into 7500 output samples. or for every 10 input samples, you need to turn it into 15 output samples.  or for every 2 input samples, you need to turn it into 3 output samples.  looks like 3 polyphases to me.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how many steps must the switch be rotated then? 3 or 2?

Comment: the input pointer only has integer values.  this pointer index advances by 1 every time an input samples is received.  the output pointer, which has both integer and fractional parts, advances by 2/3 of a sample each time an output sample is transmitted.